# How to execute maven liquibase pom from an external project's pom?

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

My maven project is dependent on a database schema created through another external project via liquibase.
For testing my project, I need to generate this database structure on my machine. 
Is there a way to specify the liquibase project details(group id, artifact, version,etc. and requisite liquibase parameters) in my project's pom itself so that the db structure is generated before any tests are executed.

**P.S.:** I know I can use something like below if the project actually exists in my machine:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>create-unitttest-db-schema</id>
                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipSchemaCreation}</skip>
                    <executable>mvn</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-f</argument>
                        <argument>../proj-liquibase-db/pom.xml</argument>
                        <argument>-P${proj.test.liquibase.create.profile},create</argument>
                        <argument>clean</argument>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                        <argument>-DdefaultSchemaName=${proj.test.schema.unittest}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I want to specify the `proj-liquibase-db`'s project coordinates here instead of the path to its pom file.

**P.P.S:** If it is not possible, then please let me know and suggest some alternatives as I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

you can unpack the artifact generated by the project containing the liquibase xml files in a subfolder of your "target" directory using the dependency plugin. 
The goal should be dependency:unpack. 
Then you just have to configure liquibase in your test classes in order to load these files.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dependency:unpack, you should execute liquibase jar by adding your project jar in class path and supplying other requisite parameters(like db details etc.).

Comment: If the project is managed with Maven, you should use it to setup all the stuff required by the execution of your tests. 
With the approach that I suggested you can bind the unpack to the process-resources phase of the maven lifecycle.
So Maven will take care to make the liquibase files available before entering in the test phase.
Then you just need to configure your test context to execute liquibase. 
You won’t need any manual actions and everything will be managed by maven and stored in your SCM repository together with the test’s source code.